# Working with view model and Razor via javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, viewmodel

I have a view model that contains a list of 'Songs'.
Now I don't wan't the view to walk through all the list so in java script I did:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() + 5 > $(document).height()) {    
        @foreach (var item in Model.Songs.Skip(Number).Take(20))
        {
             //do something
        }
        Number = Number + 20;
    }
});
```

The problem is that the Razor variable 'Number' isn't changed so I always load the same entries. I don't want to make an ajax call every time the scroller reachs the bottom, I already have my Model for the page, I just don't want to work with all of it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this i think is parse the model collection to javascript object(array)

first you need create the html helper method (will be usefull anyway for another situations) like

```
  using Newtonsoft.Json;
   .....
     public static HtmlString ToJson(this HtmlHelper helper, object obj)
     {
         return MvcHtmlString.Create(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj));
     }
```

then convert your model property to js object.

```
<script>
    var songs = @Html.ToJson(Model.Songs.Skip(Number).Take(20))
</script>
```

thats all. works for me.